# VB Script output specific Values

Tags: variables, vbscript, split

I figure that I could post this as a unique way of returning output as text instead of integers to see if this can help others that are having the same issue as I am having.

What I'm trying to accomplish is holding the output of the command, but then channeling a specific output out as a text instead of being interger based.

Here's what I have so far, and I'm currently stuck on filtering the output.  I know that I can use the mid command, but since the output in general from this command is fluid, I can't use mid to count specific characters.

The command in question is PowerShell.exe manage-bde -status C:
The output is this:

```
Volume C: [OSDisk]
[OS Volume]

    Size:                 118.24 GB
    BitLocker Version:    Windows 7
    Conversion Status:    Fully Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100%
    Encryption Method:    AES 256
    Protection Status:    Protection On
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: None
    Key Protectors:
        Numerical Password
        TPM
```

I need to pull some information from say for instance Conversion Status.  I want it to tell me if it's 100%, or 0%...or whatever it is.  I can't seem to pull just that line.

Here's what I have so far.

```
dim outputArray
dim inputText
dim message
Dim strText


Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = ObjShell.Exec("PowerShell.exe manage-bde"" -status C:")
Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
inputText = strText

outputArray = split(inputText,"Converstion Status:")

for each x in outputArray
  message = message & x & vbCRLF
next

msgbox message

Loop
```

This does a line by line pull, and I know that Conversion Status is the 3rd line, so maybe something to that effect of channeling that line and echoing the 100% to a variable that I can store as a separate output.

Update:  I decided not to go through the approach of parsing the output to a text file.  There has to be a better way and shorter code to accomplish this methodology, plus if Bitlocker variables get changed around on the output, my line methodology might not work.

I'm now trying to see if I can use the for /F search approach to find the string and set the variable.  The goal for me to do all of this is to add it to a registry key that will contain these values for reporting

Here's my revised code.

```
dim outputArray
dim inputText
dim message
Dim strText
dim line
dim testCase
dim strConversion
dim Currentline


Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = ObjShell.Exec("PowerShell.exe manage-bde"" -status C:")
Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
strConversion = "for /F ""delims="" %%a in (strText) do do findstr /M /i /C:'Conversion' C:\%i var=%%a"
Wscript.echo strConversion


Loop
```

This does a line by line pull, and I know that Conversion Status is the 3rd line, so maybe something to that effect of channeling that line and echoing the 100% to a variable that I can store as a separate output.

Update:  I decided not to go through the approach of parsing the output to a text file.  There has to be a better way and shorter code to accomplish this methodology, plus if Bitlocker variables get changed around on the output, my line methodology might not work.

I'm now trying to see if I can use the for /F search approach to find the string and set the variable.  The goal for me to do all of this is to add it to a registry key that will contain these values for reporting.

Here's my revised code.

```
dim outputArray
dim inputText
dim message
Dim strText
dim line
dim testCase
dim strConversion
dim Currentline


Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = ObjShell.Exec("PowerShell.exe manage-bde"" -status C:")
Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
strConversion = "for /F ""delims="" %%a in (strText) do findstr /M /i /C:'Conversion' C:\%i var=%%a"
Wscript.echo strConversion


Loop
```

So far when running it, it parrots back the line back 14 times which is the number of lines when you run the command straight. So, it is seeing it, just not fully parsing the data.  "Conversion" is one the strings that I'm having it check for.

Another reason I don't want to do longer code is this is part of a script that already has quite a few lines, and this will be a final sub process.

Comment: Did you want to store the third line : Conversion Status:    Fully Encrypted ?

Comment: Yes...I have more that I need to store, but if I can get one going, I can get the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the output into array like this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim arrData,Data
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    ,WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End If

arrData = Run_PS_Script
MsgBox arrData(6)
'To get all data from this loop For...Next
For Each Data in arrData
    MsgBox Data
Next

'*****************************************************************
Function Run_PS_Script()
    Dim WshShell,Command,PSFile,ret,fso,file,text,Temp
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Temp = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    Command = "cmd /c echo manage-bde -status C: ^|" &_ 
    "Out-File %temp%\output.txt -Encoding ascii > %temp%\PSFile.ps1"
    PSFile = WshShell.Run(Command,0,True)
    ret = WshShell.Run("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File %temp%\PSFile.ps1",0,True)
    Set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    text = ReadFile(Temp &"\output.txt","byline") 
    Run_PS_Script=text
End Function
'*****************************************************************
Function ReadFile(path,mode)
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const TriStateUseDefault = -2
    Dim objFSO,objFile,i,contents,strLine
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If mode = "unicode" Then
        Set objFile = objFSO.opentextfile(path,,,true)
        contents = objFile.ReadAll
        ReadFile = contents
        objFile.Close
    End If
    If mode = "byline" then
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path,ForReading)
        Dim arrFileLines()
        i = 0
        Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
            Redim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
            strLine = objFile.ReadLine
            strLine = Trim(strLine)
            If Len(strLine) > 0 Then
                arrFileLines(i) = strLine
                i = i + 1
                ReadFile = arrFileLines
            End If    
        Loop
        objFile.Close
    End If
    If mode = "all"  Then
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(path,ForReading)
        contents = objFile.ReadAll
        ReadFile = contents
        objFile.Close
    End If
End Function
'*****************************************************************
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I want to post another variation again.  How about this?

```
dim outputArray
dim inputText
dim message
Dim strText
Dim MyArray

conversion = "Conversion Status:"

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = ObjShell.Exec("PowerShell.exe manage-bde"" -status C:")
Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadLine()
inputText = strText


outputArray = split(inputText,"Conversion Status:")

for each i in outputArray
 output = i 
  next

position = InStr(1, strText,conversion, 1)  


msgbox position

Loop
```

I've got it now where it will return the 0 or 5 value for the line.  How can I convert the 5 response back to actual text that came from that line?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of pulling values from an array of strings in VBS:

```
' let us mock out our expected data returned from the disk
Dim sampleData(100)
sampleData(0) = "Volume C: [OSDisk]"
sampleData(1) = "[OS Volume]"
sampleData(2) = ""
sampleData(3) = "    Size:                 118.24 GB"
sampleData(4) = "    BitLocker Version:    Windows 7"
sampleData(5) = "    Conversion Status:    Fully Encrypted"
sampleData(6) = "    Percentage Encrypted: 100%"
sampleData(7) = "    Encryption Method:    AES 256"
sampleData(8) = "    Protection Status:    Protection On"
sampleData(9) = "    Lock Status:          Unlocked"
sampleData(10) = "    Identification Field: None"
sampleData(11) = "    Key Protectors:"
sampleData(12) = "        Numerical Password"
sampleData(13) = "        TPM"

'create a function to parse out the values you want
Function returnValueFromData(sampleData,fieldName)
        For each infoLine in sampleData
        If InStr(infoline,fieldName) Then
            infoline = Trim(Replace(infoline,fieldName,""))
            returnValueFromData = infoline
       End If
    Next
End Function


'now, we can use our function above to grab whatever field we want

'get the size of the disk
dim size
size = returnValueFromData(sampleData,"Size:")
wscript.echo size


'get the lock status of the disk
dim lockStatus
lockStatus = returnValueFromData(sampleData,"Lock Status:")
wscript.echo  lockStatus

'shorthand to get the encryption algorithm
wscript.echo returnValueFromData(sampleData,"Encryption Method:")
```